# How to show side menu icon in particular forms only

Tags: codenameone

I have side menu in my apps. But since i have many icons in the titlebar, i want to keep the side menu icon only in particular forms. I used hideLeftSideMenuBool true from theme constant but the icon disappears from all the form.

Update 1: The icon appears at the bottom of side menu itself that is of no use. It should appear at the toolbar / titlebar.

```
@Override
protected void beforeMenuForm(Form f) {
    Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
    t.setUIID("TitleArea");
    f.setToolBar(t);
    Label titleIcon = new Label();
    titleIcon.setIcon(theme.getImage("app-icon.png").scaledHeight(t.getHeight() + 50));
    titleIcon.setUIID("smallFont");
    t.setTitleComponent(titleIcon);

    showAllCommands(f);

    //the icon appears at the bottom of side menu itself that is of no use
    f.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("", FontImage.MATERIAL_MENU, e -> ((SideMenuBar)f.getMenuBar()).openMenu(null));
}

public void showAllCommands(Form f) {
   Command home = new Command("  Home", homeIcon) {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            showForm("MenuForm", this);
        }
    };
    f.addCommand(home);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hide side menu flag is global.

The menu only appears if you add commands/components to the side menu. If you don't add them it won't show up.

If you want the menu button to only appear on some forms you need to disable it entirely and add a menu button of your own to the left side of the forms you want to show. Something like this should work:

```
toolbar.addMaterialCommandToLeftSide("", FontImage.MATERIAL_MENU, e -> toolbar.openSideMenu());
```

Comment: yeah i have commands in all the forms. But i only want to keep the side menu icon in home screen and other few forms. In the forms with no side menu icon, one can swipe and see the side menu. Isn't it possible to do. Or if that is hard, i want side menu icon only in home but side menu commands in all the forms.

Comment: Assuming you use the Toolbar, if you don't physically invoke addCommandToSideMenu or something like that in a specific form the side menu won't appear.

Comment: Actually i need side menu in all forms but without side menu icon in titlebar. If user swipe the left screen of the device, side menu appears. However I need sidemenu icon in home screen only. How can I do that?

Comment: I did that but it is not working. However the menu icon appears at the bottom of the side menu itself that is of no use. I have updated the code what i had done so far. Plz have a look at it in the question above.

Comment: Sorry I had an obvious mistake in the code it should have been `addMaterialCommandToLeftSide` and not to side menu naturally...

Comment: a small correction, it is not leftSide, its addMaterialCommandToLeftBar. It works great. Thanks man...

Comment: It works in old side menu... How to make it work on on top side menu?

Comment: Edited the answer with a newer universal syntax that works everywhere